# How to determine if there is no event fired in LWC or the component that fire event is not included in record page

Tags: lightning-web-components, event

I am working on LWC which scenario that there is one component that fire an event through checkbox which is optional for other component to use it or not. Let say if the component with event is included in record page, then the other component should able to listen to it. If there is not component included, the other component should run as per local requirement.

The issue is I am not able to get it work when component that fire event is not included. The component is working if all component is included. However if I only installed other component without the event component, the other component not able to proceed. It seem like it is not even proceed after registerListener part.

```
>  //the code in component that fire event              
>  this.error = undefined;
>             JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
>             this.isFlag=result.isFlag;
>       
>             this.checkboxRecord = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
>             if(isFlag){
>                 this.isChecked = !this.isChecked;
>                 fireEvent(this.pageRef, 'RetrieveCheckboxRecord', this.checkboxRecord);
>             }
>             else{
>                 fireEvent(this.pageRef, 'RetrieveCheckboxRecord', this.checkboxRecord);
>             }
```

This is component that has listener

```
registerListener('RetrieveCheckboxRecord', this.handleEvent, this);//this is work when component is included

//how I can detect if 'RetrieveCheckboxRecord' is there and if not there I can perform other process?
```

How I can make my component flexible to listen to the event and also to work if there is no event detected.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this. The pubsub model, as well as events in general, are one-way communication, and don't care if there is anything listening on the far end. Also, you'd have to deal with race conditions depending on which component loads first. You could try to do some sort of two-way communication, where each sends out an event when the component loads, and both listen for an event. Then, you can set some sort of time out where if no response is received, then do your alternative action. Even this might be subject to race conditions depending on available bandwidth. You might want to choose an alternative design that doesn't rely on events.